# Importing tt_news articles in typo3

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I have imported over 1000 articles from one version of tt_news (2.5.2) to the latest version, I also imported the news categories.  Everything seemed to come across except the news categories don't appear to be assigned to the articles if you view them in list > news articles folder, but they do appear when you go into the table in the database. eg the article with uid = 1 has category 2 assigned to it in the tt_news table but when you view it in list > news articles it says has no categories assigned. Is there some bulk action I can use here to get all the categories assigned?

Comment: You are checking the relation between news records and categories in the `tt_news_cat_mm` table, right?

Comment: Thanks for the tip I will take a closer look at that and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`category` column in the `tt_news` table signifies the number of categories assigned to the news article while the relations between news and categories is in the `tt_news_cat_mm` table.

Therefore, check the `tt_news_cat_mm` table and see whether the relations are truly there as they are supposed to. The `uid_local` column contains UIDs of the news articles while the `uid_foreign` column contains UIDs of the news categories.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the table `tt_news_cat_mm` has all entries required for category relationship, please check the table `tt_news_cat` and `tt_news` has the same `pid` value.